# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. react-native

Tags: android, react-native

There is an error while run project on windows for android. Everything was good but I installed `react-natigation` and `react-native-gesture-handler@~1.0.14` than I started project with `react-native run-android` command.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Could not read path 'D:\ProjectFolder\android\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\androidx\lifecycle'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. If somebody need this, remove `react-navigation` and install `@react-navigation/native`